# React MDL: No drawer button with standalone drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a web view with my layout using basic React setup and react mdl (https://react-mdl.github.io/react-mdl) components. Of course I do have mdl css on my template.
I want to use the drawer components from `React MDL` with my custom layout. So far, i have this in my layout:

```
<div className="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <Header/>
  <Drawer title="Title">
   <Navigation>
      <a href="">Link</a>
      <a href="">Link</a>
      <a href="">Link</a>
      <a href="">Link</a>
   </Navigation>
  </Drawer>
</div>
```

Rendered drawer:

```
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
  <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
  <nav class="mdl-navigation">
    <a href="" class="mdl-navigation__link">Link</a>
    <a href="" class="mdl-navigation__link">Link</a>
    <a href="" class="mdl-navigation__link">Link</a>
    <a href="" class="mdl-navigation__link">Link</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Problem is it render ok but there are no **drawer button** generated. In [demo layout](https://react-mdl.github.io/react-mdl/components/layout/)   a div with class `mdl-layout__drawer-button` is generated beside the drawer div, and a div with class `mdl-layout__obfuscator` at the end of layout.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, cause I made a mistake by using `material-design-lite`'s scrips instead of `react-mdl`'s scripts.

```
import 'react-mdl/extra/material.css'
import 'react-mdl/extra/material.js'
```

Hope this helps!